# How to fix 'Command raised an exception: KeyError: '427924596164132864' in discord.py

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I am trying to create a discord bot that gives peoples wins and then stores it into a json file. When I run the command ?win @ I run into an error that displays their id within the error. I believe this is because  their id is not in the json file. However I want my code to create an entry for their id and wins if it is not already inside the json file. Here are my functions and command.

open wins

```
async def open_wins(user):
    users = await get_win_data()

    if str(user.id) in users:                         
        return False

    users[str(user.id)] = {"Wins": 0} 

    with open('leaderboard.json',"w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
    return True
```

Get win data

```
async def get_win_data():
    with open("leaderboard.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    return users
```

win code

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_role("Draft Manager")
async def win(ctx,member: discord.Member = None ):
    if not member:
        member = ctx.author
        await open_wins(member)

    users = await get_win_data()
    user = member

    onewin = 1

    await ctx.send(f"You just gained {onewin} win ")

    users[str(user.id)]["Wins"] += onewin

    with open("leaderboard.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f, indent=4)
```

Here is my json file

```
{
    "325837218222440460": {
        "Wins": 1
    }
}
```

I would like to the note the win command only works when I do "?win" but when I do "?win <@user>" thats when I get an error.

Comment: "I believe this is because their id is not in the json file. However I want my code to create an entry for their id and wins if it is not already inside the json file. Here are my functions and command." Okay, well, obviously your json doesn't have such data in there. Did you try to make sure that the entry-creation code actually runs? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to at least demonstrate some understanding of the situation.

Comment: Is your json file intended to be an empty dictionary?

Comment: @JohnGordon I have updated my json file, for some reason when I run just "?win" it will create the entry but when I try to do "?win <@user>" it does not work

Comment: Your `await open_wins(member)` is under the `if not member`. Have you checked if this causes any problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `await open_wins(member)` only when `member` is None.
But if you use "?win <@user>", `@user` may be still not recorded to your file. So, you need to use `await open_wins(member)` function in all cases.

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_role("Draft Manager")
async def win(ctx,member: discord.Member = None ):
    if not member:
        member = ctx.author
    await open_wins(member)

    users = await get_win_data()
    user = member

    onewin = 1

    await ctx.send(f"You just gained {onewin} win ")

    users[str(user.id)]["Wins"] += onewin

    with open("leaderboard.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f, indent=4)
```